# Index.html script files are not found when uploaded to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using windows 10 home edition. I have a front end application that I am able to display on my computer browser. I have uploaded the front end to an S3 bucket on AWS. I use Lambda for the backend. I added some js files to my index.html that are not found when uploaded to S3 bucket.

This Index.html file works find on my computer. When uploaded to AWS is cannot find the js files.

```
<body>
 <app-root></app-root>

<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" 
src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

This is the error on AWS browser:

```
styles.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 
404 ()
polyfills.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 
404 ()
runtime.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 
404 ()
main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 
()
polyfills.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 
404 ()
```

Comment: Did you upload the JS files to the same location as the index.html file? Are they public?

Comment: I found my answer on reddit. I added to the orgin path in cloudfront that I needed to remove..

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same issue, my bucket was missing a setting as bellow:

1. Open your **AWS Management Console** and navigate to S3 Service;
2. Open the bucket which you are facing the issue "your_file.extension:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
3. Click in properties and check, in case you have a static web hosting, if the option is enabled

[image: SW Properties]

4. If not enabled, make sure you inform the right information and that you select the option "use this bucket to host a website" and that you inform the index document:

[image: Static Website Hosting]

**Source**: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html